# Trying to import a matrix as a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays

I hope whoever is reading this is having a nice day.
I am attempting to read a matrix from a file arranged into rows and columns in a 2D array such that X1 in the first row is in entry [0,0] in python.

the input file looks something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

Whenever I attempt to read the array back it is only a single column of data from the first row:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as inputfile:
for line in inputfile:
    loadedMatrix = inputfile.read()
```

This, of course, returns an error that mixing iteration and read methods would mess things up. However when I do it without a for loop, as I said, I'm only getting the first row. Maybe someone else can point me in the right direction? Also I am avoiding numpy as I want the program to run out of box with a basic python installation.

Comment: Do you want to load it into nested Python lists or into something like a NumPy array? For the second case you have [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). For the first case, something like `[list(map(int, line.split())) for line in inputfile]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine -

```
with open('untitled.txt', 'r') as inputfile:
    loadedMatrix = [line.strip().split() for line in inputfile]
```

or if you want integers

```
loadedMatrix = [list(map(int, line.strip().split())) for line in inputfile]
```

- You forgot the indent.
- inputfile.read() reads the whole file at once. So in the loop you were reading first line and storing it in variable 'line' and the rest of the file was given to 'loadedMatrix' as a string